# Can I scroll WKInterfaceGroup programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacegroup

I have a label with a long text and a button inside a WKInterfaceGroup.
Can I scroll the group to top on the button's touch handler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this since WatchOS 4. 
The WKInterfaceController has a function for this.

```
func scroll(to object: WKInterfaceObject, at scrollPosition: WKInterfaceScrollPosition, animated: Bool)
```

Simply specify the `object` (this could for example be a `WKInterfaceGroup`) you want to scroll to, and specify the `scrollPosition` on the screen it should scroll to (in your case `.top`) and you're good. So in your WKInterfaceController class:

```
scroll(to: objectToShowAtTheTopOfTheScreen, at: .top, animated: true)
```

[Read more on this in the Apple Developer documentation for WKInterfaceController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/2874208-scroll)

[And the possible values for `scrollPosition`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacescrollposition)

Comment: For me, it only works if I assign a fixed height to the group. if the whole screen has match content size, it doesn't work. It doesn't say anything about that in the documentation. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

No. The only way to programmatically scroll an interface with WatchKit is by scrolling to a specific row in a `WKInterfaceTable`.